# Selenium JS alert

Tags: python, selenium

[pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI1vC.png)im working on a web automation project and ran into this problem
This box does not show anywhere in the html code (looks like a chrome pop up) how do i handle this in the code ?
I am using selenium with python.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

*You can pass username and password in this popup like:*

```
driver.get("protocol://Usename:Password@URL Address");
```

***OR***

```
URL = "https://{username}:{password}@www.example.com"
driver.executeScript("window.open('"+URL+"')")
```

*Hope this will solve your issue.*

Comment: @ali_alm, Please accept the answer if your issue is resolved.